# why some command line argument and their tag are together?

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

I don't know the exact name of `-a` in `ls -a`, I just call it the tag in the title.

It is very common that you pass a value (file.c) to the argument:

```sh
gcc -c file.c
```

What I am curious about is this kind of code

```sh
gcc -fPIC -c file1.c
```

Why are the -f and PIC together?

Because PIC is a built-in content?

Well, I have seen this kind of code:

```
ldid -Stest.xml gdb
```

The `-S` and argument (`test.xml`) are together.

I think it is total reasonable to write this way:

```
ldid -S test.xml gdb
```

So why this?

Is this a historical problem?

Is there a inner reason or just it is the preference of the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you're comparing are somewhat fundamentally different.

The argument `-fPIC` is an argument in its whole, you can't just replace the `PIC` part with any other string and expect it to work.

The (typically filename) arguments are pretty much free-form, hence the separation.

There are in-between arguments, e.g. `-march=...` where the `...` can be filled in from a set of known values. In some programs and for some options, the `=` is replaced by a space. An example of this is the `-o` option, which sets the output filename for e.g. `gcc`, which is used as follows:

```
gcc main.cpp -o output
```

So consistency leaves to be desired any direction you look at it.

Most interfaces don't even match [POSIX conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):